# Display a photo retrived from firebase on ionic 4 App

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I have an ionic4 app that I retrieve some photo from firebase storage and show it on html page in my app, now I just could showed the photo in a console and I couldn't showed it on a page.

Can someone help me that how can I display a photo on **html page** please.

My code is below

**home.page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  storageRef: AngularFireStorageReference;

  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  display() {
    this.storageRef = this.afStorage.ref('rasool/download2.jpg');
    this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => console.log(url));
  }


}
```

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <p>its work sir</p>
  <ion-button (click)="display()">click me</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: why i should to click the button to display the photo ?? can i display it directly on the page ???

Answer (score 0):

```
    // home.page.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireStorage, AngularFireStorageReference } from 'angularfire2/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
  storageRef: AngularFireStorageReference;
  public imageUrl = '';
  constructor(private afStorage: AngularFireStorage) { }
  display() {
    this.storageRef = this.afStorage.ref('rasool/download2.jpg');
    this.storageRef.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => this.imageUrl = url);
  }
}

// home.page.html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Ionic Blank
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
  <p>its work sir</p>
  <img src="{{imageUrl}}" />
  <ion-button (click)="display()">click me</ion-button>
</ion-content>`enter code here`
```

Comment: why i should to click the button to display the photo ?? can i display it directly on the page ???

Comment: @RasoolALmusawie then put you code in `ionview` events or in `constructor`.

Comment: can u tell me how do that ??